# PHP - Editing csv header displayed in table html and saving it back to the csv

Tags: javascript, php, csv, contenteditable

I have uploaded a csv file and displayed it on html using php.

```
function jj_readcsv($filename, $header=false) {
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
echo '<table>';
//display header row if true
if ($header) {
    $csvcontents = fgetcsv($handle);
    echo '<tr id='edit1' contenteditable='false'>';
    foreach ($csvcontents as $headercolumn) {
        echo "<th>$headercolumn</th>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
// displaying contents
while ($csvcontents = fgetcsv($handle)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($csvcontents as $column) {
        echo "<td>$column</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
fclose($handle);
}
```

I added a javascript function to make the header tags editable, toggling it.

```
<button onclick='edittab();'>Edit</button>
<button onclick='savetab();'>Save</button>
<script type='text/javascript'>function edittab() 
{ 
document.getElementById('edit1').contentEditable=true;
}
function savetab() 
{ 
document.getElementById('edit1').contentEditable=false;
}
</script>
```

The problem i am coming up with is, when the headers are updated, how to save the updated headers along with the rest of the data into the same file. 
What i came up with was that if i am able to store the updated headers into a different variable and store it into the required csv using "fputcsv" along with the rest of the data, i'll be able to achieve the desired result but i am unable to find a way to store the headers into a variable(preferrably array form).
Any insights would be helpful.

Comment: so do you want to submit a form (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)? or to send an Ajax with all the info?

Comment: it would be great if it would be saved without using input tags in the table.